# How to receive multiple POST requests from same client on the server

Tags: java, sockets, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to write a java server and client such that the client sends the server a POST request with some xml string read from a file as payload, the server fetches the request from the client and sends it an acknowledgment, and this process repeats till all the xml strings that the client has have been sent (as separate POST requests).

I have made the code for 1 single exchange of request and response between the client and server. But I am unable to extend it for multiple requests from the same client because the client waits for server's response and the server's response is not sent to the client till I write `wr.close()` or `socket.close()` after writing bytes in the DataOutputStream object. But as soon as I write either of the two commands, my connection between the server and client closes and the client needs to establish connection all over again in order to send the second request.

This is my server side function that receives the request and sends the response:

```java
public HTTPServer(int port) {
        try {
            private ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            private Socket socket = server.accept();
            int ind = 0;

            while (ind<19) {

                //socket is an instance of Socket
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader);

                //code to read and print headers
                String headerLine = null;
                while ((headerLine = br.readLine()).length() != 0) {
                    System.out.println(headerLine);
                }

                ind++;

                //send response to the client
                Date today = new Date();
                String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + today;
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(httpResponse);
                wr.flush();
            }
            socket.close();         // or wr.close()

        } catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

This is my client side code:

```java
public void postMessage() throws IOException {
        // string to read message from input
        File folder = new File("path/to/my/files");
        String[] listOfFiles = folder.list();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            File file = new File(listOfFiles[i]);
            Scanner sc = null;
            try {
                sc = new Scanner(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);

            // Send post request
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            String line = "";
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                line += sc.nextLine();
                line += '\n';
            }
            wr.writeBytes(line);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();


            // read response
            BufferedReader in;
            if (200 <= conn.getResponseCode() && conn.getResponseCode() <= 299) {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            } else {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
            }
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        }
    }
```

Unless I write `socket.close()` or `wr.close()` after `wr.flush()`, my response is not sent to the client and the client keeps waiting for it, but as soon as I do, the server socket is closed and the code terminates. How can I send response to my client without having to close the socket?

EDIT:
This is updated HTTP Client code, which uses sockets to send HTTP request, but the error persists.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        Socket socket = new Socket(addr, 8080);
        boolean autoflush = true;

        // string to read message from input
        File folder = new File("/Users/prachisingh/IdeaProjects/requests_responses");
        String[] listOfFiles = folder.list();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i]);
            File file = new File("/Users/prachisingh/IdeaProjects/requests_responses/" + listOfFiles[i]);

            Scanner sc = null;
            try {
                sc = new Scanner(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String line = "";
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                line += sc.nextLine();
                line += '\n';
            }

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), autoflush);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            // send an HTTP request to the web server
            out.println("POST / HTTP/1.1");
            out.println("Host: http://localhost:8080");
            out.println(line);
            out.println();

            // read the response
            boolean loop = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8096);
            while (loop) {
                if (in.ready()) {
                    int r = 0;
                    while (r != -1) {
                        r = in.read();
                        sb.append((char) r);
                    }
                    loop = false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
        socket.close();
    }
```